# How to resolve parameter file error

Tags: oracle

I log on to my database but giving me this error message

> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
>   LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initAKINTT.ora'

How can i resolve the problem ?

Comment: are you able to read the paramter file? try `cat '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initAKINTT.ora'`

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly set ORACLE_SID environment variable to match your database name?

Assuming you didn't delete the spfile and pfile, incorrect ORACLE_SID setting might be causing the error, since when you issue "startup" command, Oracle will search for spfile in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs, and if it doesn't find, will alternatively search for pfile in format init.ora

So, if I have a database named test (lowercase), and I export ORACLE_SID in uppercase and attempt to start the instance, this error will ocurr.

[oracle@oracle $] export ORACLE_SID=TESTE
[oracle@oracle $] sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> startup...

-- ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file

In this case, there is no such file as initTEST.ora, only inittest.ora

So:

Check if you're using proper case while exporting ORACLE_SID and if the name is correct.

Given your db has been configured through dbca, you can find the name entry at:

[oracle@oracle $] cat /etc/oratab

Answer (score -1):

1. Create `pfile` manually or get it from old database and edit it
2. start database
3. `create spfile from pfile` [CREATE SPFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6016.htm#SQLRF01315) (Oracle Docs)

Comment: It helps if you provide additional references and working examples. You could clean up your answer some more and provide a good working solution. It also helps if you read the [help on formatting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to format your text correctly.